# How to make Webpage run in background?

Tags: javascript, html, list, listview

Sorry if I am not posting in the correct way or in the correct spot, but I am in dire need of help and you are kinda my last resort.

## My problem is:

We have Monitor A and Monitor B.

On monitor B I need to have a webpage open at all times that has a list of things that refreshes automatically every 30s.

Problem is, when I click anywhere else on Monitor A, that automatic refresh stops and it does not start again until I click anywhere on that webpage on Monitor B.

Is there a way to make that list think that the webpage is not in the background so it won't stop the refresh?

I can not use an autorefresh for the whole webpage because if I do that, it will also erase all the filters from my list.

I have tried using it always on top, but it does not help :(

If someone is able to help me with this, I would gladly appreciate it

You are my last resort other than connecting a laptop to it

Comment: you could try to have a look at `puppeteer`

Comment: Before anything else. I want to mention that I have 0 developer/programer skills and also do not have access to the script of the website, or server, or whatever it is. Am I able to use/install pupeteer without the aforementioned ?

Comment: asking programming questions with no programming skills will always be an issue  but you do not in fact need the source code of the webpage